# Scrollbars for a .jpg image on a Tkinter Canvas in Python

Tags: python, scrollbar, tkinter, jpeg

I'm trying to make a jpeg on a canvas scrollable but I can't seem to get my scrollbars to work. Here's some example code:

```
from Tkinter import *
import Image, ImageTk

root = Tk()

frame = Frame(root, bd=2, relief=SUNKEN)

frame.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
frame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

xscrollbar = Scrollbar(frame, orient=HORIZONTAL)
xscrollbar.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=E+W)

yscrollbar = Scrollbar(frame)
yscrollbar.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=N+S)

canvas = Canvas(frame, bd=0, xscrollcommand=xscrollbar.set, yscrollcommand=yscrollbar.set)
canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=N+S+E+W)

File = "jpg filepath here"
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(File))
canvas.create_image(0,0,image=img, anchor="nw")

xscrollbar.config(command=canvas.xview)
yscrollbar.config(command=canvas.yview)

frame.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Did you forget to type `from PIL` in the second import or `Image`and `Imagetk`is some other module?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to tell the canvas what part of the drawing space to scroll. Use something like:

```
canvas.config(scrollregion=canvas.bbox(ALL))
```

More information can be found here: http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#coordinate-systems